# HAProxy as selective forward proxy and load balancer

Tags: haproxy

I'm looking at doing some sidecar proxying. At the moment we have squid proxies as internet proxies and haproxy successfully load balancing those proxy connections.

What I want to do though is separate out some internal services for local load balancing. All are TLS.

Therefore if the connect http request has a specific domain name, I'd like to use a different backend. But at the moment I cannot figure out how to do this.

This works fine:

`curl -v -x http://127.0.0.1:5000 https://google.com`

Going to our squid forward proxies successfully. But the following does not use the alternative backend for out git servers:

`curl -v -x http://127.0.0.1:5000 https://git.business.dom`

I've tried matching the domain name on the incoming request, but I can't get a match. I also cannot see any other way of matching for the URL in a HTTP CONNECT method request.

This always ends up getting routed to the default backend squid proxies

```
frontend main
    mode http
    bind 127.0.0.1:5000

    acl connect_git req.payload(0,0) -m sub git.business.dom
    use_backend git if connect_git

    default_backend             forward_internet_proxies

backend git
    mode http
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor header X-Client
    option forwardfor
    balance roundrobin
    http-check expect rstatus (2..|3..)
    server git1 git1.business.dom:443 weight 1 ssl verify none
    server git2 git2.business.dom:443 weight 1 ssl verify none

backend forward_internet_proxies
    balance     roundrobin
    mode http
    server proxy1 192.168.1.220:3128 check
    server proxy2 192.168.1.221:3128 check
```

Answer (score 0):

The dumb thing is, the HTTP CONNECT method is just that - a plain HTTP connect request. This includes a host header which can be matched to select the backend.

HAProxy also has a pre-defined ACL for the CONNECT method so that can also be used.

The confusion came because of using `-i git.business.dom` but the host header contains the domain and port number for the connect. So we need to match `-i git.business.dom:443` or else use the `-m sub` option instead.

So we end up with:

```
    acl githost hdr(host) -i git.business.dom:443
    use_backend git if githost METH_CONNECT
```

This would require the git backend servers to handle the `HTTP CONNECT` request, otherwise this will not work.

If you're using nginx then you can use a plugin to enable support of the `HTTP CONNECT` request.